# Web api return values for async methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I'm a bit confused with `HttpResponseMessage` and `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`.

If I'm using the `HttpClient` method `PostAsync()` to post data I need to give the Web Service method the `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` instead of `HttpResponseMessage` as return value as far as I understood things.

If I use `Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, myError.ToString());`
then I'm only getting the Response message object but not the `Task` object.

So my question here is how do I have to create the Fitting return for async calls to web api methods?
(thus are my understandings there correct and if so how to best transform the message object int a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` object)

The original code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage DeviceLogin(MyDevice device)
{
    EnummyError myError = EnummyError.None;

    // Authenticate Device.
    myError = this.Authenticate(device);

    if (myError != EnummyError.None)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, myError.ToString());
    }
}
```

The updated Method header:

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> DeviceLogin(MyDevice device)
```

Comment: I’m not following your question. Do you have some code to show that would explain the issue? You don’t really do anything with tasks yourself, the framework handles that and you just return the type you’d return anyway.

Comment: Are you using Web Api version 1 or 2?

Comment: @Baksteen visual Studio 2017 so v2    updating in a second with example code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web Api 2 has these abstraction classes which are now recommended to use. You can still use `HttpResponseMessage` (easier to follow for beginners, in my opinion), but Web Api 2 recommends using `IHttpActionResult`.

As for the return type, just did what you did before. `Task<T>` works *automagically* that way.

You also might want to check if `this.Authenticate()` has an `async` variant.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeviceLogin(MyDevice device)
{
    EnummyError myError = EnummyError.None;

    // Authenticate Device.
    myError = this.Authenticate(device);

    // Perhaps Authenticate has an async method like this.
    // myError = await this.AuthenticateAsync(device);


    if (myError != EnummyError.None)
    {
        return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, myError.ToString()));
    }
}
```

The `ResponseMessage()` method creates a `ResponseMessageResult` under water. This class derives from `IHttpActionResult` and accepts a `HttpResponseMessage` as a parameter in the constructor (which is made by `Request.CreateResponse()`).

Comment: Does Authenticate NEED an async method?

Comment: hmmm Compiler says ResponseMessage can't be converted into Task<IHttpActionResult>

Comment: works that way. question still though: do I have to use await inside? or is it a "you better should",... ?

Comment: Ah! My bad. I forgot to add `async` to the method declaration. I've updated my answer.
As for Authenticate, no it does not. But if you don't use any `await` operators for async method calls, there is no use of making this method asynchronous, as it would just run synchronously

Comment: Will have to think it over and possibly redesign / make a new question there, but this current question is solved so thnx.